# Can't create schema from `assumed` role with ALL privileges

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

For the postgresql 10 have this code:

```
CREATE DATABASE featurestore WITH OWNER admin;
CREATE ROLE editor WITH LOGIN PASSWORD XXXX NOINHERIT NOCREATEROLE;
CREATE ROLE fstore_migrations WITH NOLOGIN NOCREATEROLE;
GRANT fstore_migrations TO editor;
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE featurestore TO fstore_migrations;
```

AND then log in as editor, and

```
SET ROLE FSTORE_MIGRATIONS;
SELECT current_database()               # returns featurestore
SELECT SESSION_USER, CURRENT_USER;      # returns editor, fstore_migrations
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS BUILDINGS   # (psycopg2.errors.InsufficientPrivilege) permission denied for database featurestore
```

What did I miss? Is there any way to see permissions on database (rather than specific tables/schemas ?

Comment: In your setup, "CREATE  ROLE editor" should be run before "CREATE DATABASE". In the "editor" session, the role 'featurestore_migrations" does not exist and I don't think you need to run "SET ROLE fstore_migrations". With these 2 modifications, these scripts are OK in my environment.

Comment: thanks, those are my mystakes in writing the problem here. Why don't I need to `set role`? My idea is to have one role (editor) as a credential-holder, then specific roles to perform specific tasks (for logging purposes), so ideally `editor` won't be able to create schemas on it's own (that is why `noinherit`)

Comment: In this specific case, you don't need "set role" because 'editor' is the owner of the database and you should be able to create schema with or without "set role". (I have tested successfully both cases using PG 10.12).

Comment: If the database is owned by 'admin', you need 'set role' and you should be able to create schema (tested successfully with PG 10.12).